# Is there a standards-compliant way to start a PHP session and echo a JavaScript script in one include() statement?

Tags: php, html

I have two scripts that I call with two PHP include() calls. The first starts a session / sets cookies, the second loads one of two JavaScript scripts. To keep things valid, I've been using the two calls but I'd like to just combine them into one.

Current setup (simplified):

```
<? include "session.php" ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<? include "scripts.php" ?>
 ...
```

What I'd like:

```
<? include "session_and_scripts.php" ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
...
```

But it's invalid markup. Now if it really doesn't matter, I'd like to do it this way. If there are serious repercussions, then I'm thinking of just echoing a DOCTYPE in the included PHP file, which I'd rather not do.

So which is better: echo the DOCTYPE, use include() twice, or use include() once and have invalid markup?

**EDIT** - The whole script (session and javascript) should ideally be fully implementable with one line of code (e.g. the one include())

Comment: These are the things that frameworks are meant to simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ob_start at first to avoid problems with session_start

```
<?php ob_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<?php include "session_and_scripts.php"; ?>
```

---

A  way that uses only 1 1file and no additional instructions:

```
<?php include "session_and_scripts.php" ?>
<!-- more head-stuff-->
</head>
<body>
<!--more content-->
```

session_and_scripts.php should do the following:

```
<?php
  //do the session stuff
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //some javascript
</script>
```

(But I would'nt say it's a good approach)

Comment: Good idea, but it still ends up involving two lines of code in separate locations. I'll edit the question a bit for clarity, but the idea is to be able to implement the whole script (session and javascript) with one line of code

Comment: The big problem that I had with this is that to make it modular, you have to be able to account for different DOCTYPES. Plus if the include fails then you have end tags for html and head, but no start ones. Maybe I'll do this, but if the include fails just have it print out a DOCTYPE, and html and head opening tags. Or maybe at the end of it all, 2 includes isn't so bad ;). Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

> But it's invalid markup. Now if it really doesn't matter, I'd like to do it this way. If there are serious repercussions, then I'm thinking of just echoing a DOCTYPE in the included PHP file, which I'd rather not do.

Assuming that you do not want to have a valid markup, there is no problem, the only restriction is that `session_start` is called before any kind of "echo"...

Assuming you want a valid markup using only one include and without echoing the `DOCTYPE` from the included file, you can save the script text into a php variable and echo it in the main page after the inclusion

```
//main page
<? include "session_and_scripts.php" ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<?php echo $script;?>


// session_and_scripts.php
<?php
session_start();
$script = '<blablabla>';
```

Comment: Yeah, this was this other consideration. Except it leads itself to the same problem: two lines. The whole script (session and javascript) should be fully implementable with one line of code.

Comment: you can't do what you want without print the doctype in the session_script.php or print the script before the doctype